# Please help me understand 注がれた in this sentence and its conjugation

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

> 信じられないほど青い目、まるで淡いサファイアのようだ。その目がハリーを観察している。そして額の傷にじっと**注がれた**。

Why did they use passive form in this sentence and what does it mean when coming after noun + に ?

Comment: その文の前に、「視線が」か「目が」などの主語はありませんか？

Comment: This is the preceded sentence:
信じられないほど青い目、まるで淡いサファイアのようだ。その目がハリーを観察している

Comment: Ah. So the subject is 目, or 視線. 「視線を注ぐ」 is a set phrase to mean "to watch/look/stare."

Comment: This is the whole chunk:
その目がハリーを観察している。その目がハリーを観察している。 そして額の傷にじっと注がれた。
I'm not sure about the subject.

Comment: Yeah, so 目が傷に注がれた "The eyes were focused on the scar." i.e., (The owner of the eyes) stared at the scar.

Comment: When you have additional information that is necessary to answer the question, please make sure you add it to the question itself rather than the comments section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **その目が**ハリーを観察している。そして額の傷にじっと**注がれた**。

The subject for the 注がれた is (その)目.

「（～に）目/視線を注ぐ」 is a set phrase to mean "to watch/look/stare (at~)".

Here it's used in the passive voice: 「目が額の傷にじっと注がれた」, literally "The eyes were focused intently on the scar on his forehead", i.e. "(The owner of the eyes) stared/gazed at the scar on his(=Harry's) forehead."

Answer (score 1):

注ぐ = pour
額の傷 = the wound on the forehead

額の傷に注がれた
was poured onto the wound on the forehead

Comment: Nope, my friend. 注がれた in this sentence doesn't mean pour or even it does, there is no point of using passing form here.

Comment: そそぐ【注ぐ】: flow into, water, pour on; sprinkle 
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/44007/meaning/m0u/%E6%B3%A8%E3%81%90/

Comment: how about concentrate ?

Comment: It depends on the subject. I need the context. I need the text that comes before that sentence. Japanese is highly dependent on  the context. It is difficult to understand a sentence out of context.

Comment: This is the preceded sentence:

信じられないほど青い目、まるで淡いサファイアのようだ。その目がハリーを観察している

Comment: 目を注ぐ is an expression. It means to stare, to look intently:
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/216401/meaning/m1u/%E7%9B%AE%E3%82%92%E6%B3%A8%E3%81%90/